# Отображение данных в TableView JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview

Знаю, что тема есть на просторах интернета, однако проблему решить не могу. Вроде все правильно, а данные не выводятся. При нажатии кнопки, открывается Stage, в котором есть TableView. Реализация:

Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static Client.NET.Client.STOP;
import static Client.NET.Client.ShowCar;
import static Client.NET.Client.getInstanceClient;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Client/FXML/Scene1.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        runStage(primaryStage);
    }

    public static void setStage(Stage stage){
        primaryStage = stage;
    }

    public static Stage getStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public static void setScene(Scene scene) {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    }

    public static Scene getScene() {
        return primaryStage.getScene();
    }

    public static void runStage(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        primaryStage = stage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("ClientProgram");
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(530);
        primaryStage.setMaxHeight(400);
        primaryStage.setMaxWidth(630);
        getInstanceClient();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

fxml таблицы:

```
<TableView fx:id="TableCars" layoutX="8.0" layoutY="9.0"prefHeight="312.0" prefWidth="586.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="23.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="6.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="9.0">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn fx:id="columnMarka" prefWidth="75.0" text="columnMarka" />
    <TableColumn fx:id="columnModel" prefWidth="75.0" text="columnModel" />
    <TableColumn fx:id="columnYear" prefWidth="75.0" text="columnYear" />
    <TableColumn fx:id="columnColor" prefWidth="75.0" text="columnColor" />
    <TableColumn fx:id="columnPrice" prefWidth="75.0" text="columnPrice" />
    <TableColumn fx:id="columnCount" prefWidth="75.0" text="columnCount" />
  </columns>
  <columnResizePolicy>
    <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
  </columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
```

Controller1:

```
public void IsAuto(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
    MakeTable makeTable = new MakeTable();
    makeTable.MakeTable();
}

class MakeTable implements Initializable {

    public void MakeTable () throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Client/FXML/ShowAuto.fxml"));
        Main.primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        Main.primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ArrayList<Goods> arrayList = ShowCar();//ShowCar - возвращает ArrayList c данными
        ObservableList<Goods> Cars = FXCollections.observableArrayList(arrayList);
        columnMarka.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Goods,String>("columnMarka"));
        columnModel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Goods,String>("columnModel"));
        columnColor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Goods,String>("columnColor"));
        columnYear.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Goods,String>("columnYear"));
        columnPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Goods,Float>("columnYear"));
        columnCount.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Goods,Integer>("columnCount"));
        TableCars.setItems(Cars);
    }
}
```

Класс Goods:

```
public class Goods {
    private Car car;
    private float price;
    private int count;

    public Goods() {
        this.car = new Car();
        this.price = 0;
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Класс Car:

```
public class Car {
    private String marka;
    private String model;
    private String color;
    private String year;

    public String getMarka() {
        return marka;
    }

    public void setMarka(String marka) {
        this.marka = marka;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

Не могу понять, что делаю не так.

Comment: Как минимум, у Вас ошибка в том, что вместо `new PropertyValueFactory<Goods, Integer>("columnCount")` должно быть `new PropertyValueFactory<Goods, Integer>("Count")` (либо в `Goods` должен быть геттер `getcolumnCount()`), для остальных по аналогии. А в первых четырех строках вместо `Goods` все-таки будет `Car`. Почитайте вот этот [ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18974290).

Comment: Спасибо большое, я этого не знал и не понимал, что за String передается в PropertyValueFactory<>(). Изменил так, как сказали, однако проблему не решило.

Comment: `PropertyValueFactory` должно точно совпадать с названием соответствующего геттера (только **без** `get`).

Comment: Это я понял. Marka.setCellValueFactory(newPropertyValueFactory<Car,String>("Marka"));  public String getMarka() { return marka;} Но все равно данные не отображаются. Сам ArrayList, который передается для вывода я проверил, он содержит элементы. Но проблема осталась

Comment: А в `columnMarka.setCellValueFactory` `columnMarka` должно совпадать с соответствующим `fx:id` в `fxml`.

Comment: В контролере:Marka.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Car,String>("Marka")); В fxml:<TableColumn fx:id="Marka" prefWidth="75.0" text="Marka" />

Comment: Это верно, а вот насчет вывода информации из вложенного объекта можете почитать [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769296/binding-nested-object-properties-to-tableview-in-javafx).

Comment: Я так понял вывести атрибуты вложенного элемента можно 2 способами первый это nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ProductStockDto, String>, 
                                                         ObservableValue<String>>() {  
    @Override  
    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ProductStockDto, String> data){  
         return data.getValue().getProducts().nameProperty();  
    }  
}); Второй переопределить toString() для класса, имеющего вложенный объект?

Comment: Насколько я понял, при переопределение метода `toString()` все поля вложенного объекта будут выводится в одну колонку, у Вас же каждому полю соответствует отдельная колонка, поэтому попробуйте первый способ.

Comment: Вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22907385) еще тоже про вложенные объекты написано.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться, много подводных камней.